# Why is my neural network training so much worse than pytorch's?

Tags: python, machine-learning, optimization, pytorch, graph-theory

So, I have a Pytorch module I've implemented, called `DAGNet`, which is basically a generalization of a standard layer-wise architecture, except instead of the neurons having to be arranged in layers, they can form an arbitrary directed acyclic graph.

One way you can use it is by defining the structure to be `A->B,C;B->D,E;C->D,E;D->F;E->F;F;`, where `A` is the input node, `F`, is the output node, so this should be equivalent to a neural network with two hidden layers, where each layer has 2 hidden units.

However, I'm getting vastly different training performance between my `DAGNet` and a Pytorch equivalent. Here is my `DAGNet`:

```
import random
from graphlib import TopologicalSorter

import numpy as np
import torch
from torch import nn

device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

class Neuron(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_inputs, n_outputs, name, activation=nn.ReLU()):
        self.name = name

        super(Neuron, self).__init__()
        self.linear = nn.Linear(n_inputs, 1).to(device)
        self.activation = activation
        self.n_outputs = n_outputs
        nn.init.kaiming_uniform_(self.linear.weight, nonlinearity='relu')

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.activation(self.linear(x)).repeat(1, self.n_outputs)

class DAGNet4(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, description_string, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Create a neural network based on a directed acyclic graph.
        @param description_string: A string describing the DAG.

        Example string:

        A->C,D,E;B->C,D,E;C->F,G,H;D->F,G,H;E->F,G,H;F->I,J,K;G->I,J,K;H->I,J,K;I->L;J->L;K->L;L;

        This implements a simple neural network with two inputs, three hidden layers, and one output layer.
        However, the DAG structure allows much more general networks to be constructed.
        """
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # First, create a standard directed acyclic graph with the information parsed from the string.
        # This will help us set up the actual neurons later.
        self.dag = {}
        for node in description_string.split(';'):
            if node == '':
                continue
            if '->' not in node:
                # Last node in the string has no outputs
                self.dag[node] = []
                continue
            node_name, inputs = node.split('->')
            inputs = inputs.split(',')
            self.dag[node_name] = inputs

        self.ts = {}
        self.so = {}
        self.recompute()

        # Display
        self.curr_fig_num = 0

    def recompute(self):
        # Reverse each edge in the topological sort to get the input edges for each neuron.
        self.input_edges = {}
        for node, edges in self.dag.items():
            for edge in edges:
                if edge in self.input_edges:
                    self.input_edges[edge].append(node)
                else:
                    self.input_edges[edge] = [node]

        # Now, create a neuron for each node in the DAG.
        # Make sure to correctly count the number of inputs for each neuron.
        self.new_neurons = {}
        for node_name, inputs in self.dag.items():
            n_inputs = 0

            if node_name not in self.input_edges:
                n_inputs = 1
            else:
                n_inputs += len(self.input_edges[node_name])

            n_outputs = len(self.dag[node_name]) if len(self.dag[node_name]) > 0 else 1

            self.new_neurons[node_name] = Neuron(n_inputs, n_outputs, node_name)

            if n_inputs == 0 or len(self.dag[node_name]) == 0:
                # If a neuron has no inputs (is an input neuron) or no outputs (is an output neuron),
                # then we don't apply an activation to it
                self.new_neurons[node_name].activation = nn.Identity()

        # Copy weights and biases from identically named neurons in `self.neurons`
        if hasattr(self, 'neurons'):
            for node_name, neuron in self.new_neurons.items():
                if node_name in self.neurons:
                    if neuron.linear.weight.data.shape == self.neurons[node_name].linear.weight.data.shape:
                        neuron.linear.weight.data = self.neurons[node_name].linear.weight.data
                        neuron.linear.bias.data = self.neurons[node_name].linear.bias.data

        # Set it to be the new neurons
        self.neurons = self.new_neurons.copy()

        del self.ts
        del self.so

        # Topologically sort the neurons to ensure that the inputs to each neuron are computed before the neuron itself.
        self.ts = TopologicalSorter(self.dag)

        self.so = list(reversed(list(self.ts.static_order())))

        self.model = nn.Sequential(*[self.new_neurons[node_name] for node_name in self.so])


    def get_neuron_outputs(self, x):
        # Run the input through the DAG to get the output.
        # Make sure to correctly pass the inputs to each neuron.

        node_names = list(self.new_neurons.keys())
        outputs = {}

        # The input (x) gets loaded into nodes that don't have any inputs.

        # To do this, we first get all the input nodes.
        input_nodes = []

        for node_name in self.so:
            if node_name not in self.input_edges:
                input_nodes.append(node_name)

        # Now, we split the input, such that each portion of the input goes into each input node.
        num_input_nodes = len(input_nodes)

        # Sort the input nodes alphabetically
        input_nodes = sorted(input_nodes)

        # Split the input into `num_input_nodes` parts
        split_input = torch.split(x, x.shape[1] // num_input_nodes, dim=1)

        # Run the input through the input nodes
        for node_name in input_nodes:
            outputs[node_name] = self.new_neurons[node_name](split_input[input_nodes.index(node_name)])

        # The rest of the nodes get their inputs from the outputs of other nodes
        for node_name in self.so:
            if node_name in self.input_edges:
                inputs = []
                for input_node in self.input_edges[node_name]:
                    # Get the subpart of the input node's output that corresponds to this node's input
                    inputs.append(torch.hsplit(outputs[input_node], len(self.dag[input_node]))[self.dag[input_node].index(node_name)])
                outputs[node_name] = self.new_neurons[node_name](torch.cat(inputs, dim=1))
        return outputs
    def forward(self, x):
        return self.get_neuron_outputs(x)[list(self.so)[-1]]


train_positions = [[1.2987529875298751], [0.03534035340353414], [0.9329493294932947], [-1.2966729667296673], [-0.1390613906139062], [0.18146181461814592], [-1.900879008790088], [1.904959049590496], [0.843908439084391], [-0.988029880298803]]
train_labels = [[2.5975059750597502], [0.07068070680706828], [1.8658986589865894], [-2.5933459334593345], [-0.2781227812278124], [0.36292362923629184], [-3.801758017580176], [3.809918099180992], [1.687816878168782], [-1.976059760597606]]

# Create a DAGNet object and train it on the data.
net = DAGNet4("A->B,C;B->D,E;C->D,E;D->F;E->F;F;").to(device)

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(net.model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)

# net(torch.Tensor(torch.Tensor([-0.56348075,  0.08711788])))

loss_fn = torch.nn.MSELoss()

losses = []
test_losses = []

for i in range(1000000):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss = loss_fn(net.forward(torch.Tensor(train_positions).to(device)), torch.Tensor(train_labels).to(device))
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    if i % 100 == 0:
        print("Step {}".format(i))
        print("Train loss: {}".format(loss.item()))

    if loss < 0.01:
        break
```

and here is the (I think) equivalent Pytorch network:

```
import torch
from torch import nn


# A simple feedforward neural network with an easily adjustable number of hidden layers and hidden units.
class SimpleNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.hidden_layers = 2
        self.hidden_units = [2, 2]
        self.activation = torch.nn.ReLU()

        layers = [torch.nn.Linear(1, self.hidden_units[0]), self.activation]
        for i in range(self.hidden_layers - 1):
            layers.append(torch.nn.Linear(self.hidden_units[i], self.hidden_units[i + 1]))
            layers.append(self.activation)
        layers.append(torch.nn.Linear(self.hidden_units[-1], 1))
        self.model = torch.nn.Sequential(*layers)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.model(x)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Split into train and test sets
    train_positions = [[1.2987529875298751], [0.03534035340353414], [0.9329493294932947], [-1.2966729667296673],
                       [-0.1390613906139062], [0.18146181461814592], [-1.900879008790088], [1.904959049590496],
                       [0.843908439084391], [-0.988029880298803]]
    train_labels = [[2.5975059750597502], [0.07068070680706828], [1.8658986589865894], [-2.5933459334593345],
                    [-0.2781227812278124], [0.36292362923629184], [-3.801758017580176], [3.809918099180992],
                    [1.687816878168782], [-1.976059760597606]]


    # print(positions)

    # Create a SimpleNet object and train it on the data.
    net = SimpleNet()
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(net.model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)
    loss_fn = torch.nn.MSELoss()

    for i in range(100000):
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss = loss_fn(net.forward(torch.Tensor(train_positions)), torch.Tensor(train_labels))
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        if i % 100 == 0:
            print("Step {}".format(i))
            print("Train loss: {}".format(loss.item()))

            if loss.item() < 0.001:
                break
```

So, I'm trying to get them to learn ten simple data points (just the map x->2x, honestly small enough to memorize). The Pytorch network always gets to below 0.01 loss in about 5000 steps; my `DAGNet`, on the other hand, gets to below 0.01 loss about 20% of the time (in around 7000 steps), and the other 80% of the time, it gets stuck at 5.2585835 loss basically forever.

This makes me think that it's an optimization issue; however, I'm not sure what significant difference exists between my implementation and the Pytorch one. Any ideas?

Comment: This isn't a programming question -- you should ask it on one of the Stack Exchange sites dedicated to machine learning.